# How do i print all the numbers in value num1, num2, num3, and the long hex in rax?

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86-64

```
Console         equ     -11

extern  GetStdHandle:   PROTO
extern  WriteFile:      PROTO
extern  ReadFile:       PROTO
extern  ExitProcess:    PROTO

.data
num1        byte    ?
num2        word    ?
num3        dword   ?
num4        qword   ?
stdin       qword   ?
stdout      qword   ?
numWrite    qword   ?

.code
mainCRTStartup      PROC
    sub rsp, 40     ;reserve shadow space

    mov rcx, CONSOLE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov stdin, rax

    ;Storing information into memory
    mov num1, 6dh
    mov num2, 7361h
    mov num3, 7369206dh
    mov rax, 216e754620h

    mov rcx, stdout         ;parm1 = console
    lea rdx, num2           ;parm2 = ASCII
    ;parm3 = total #bytes to display
    mov r8, 15
    lea r9, numWrite
    mov qword ptr [rsp+32], 0
    call ReadFile


    add rsp, 40
    mov rcx, 0
    call ExitProcess
mainCRTStartup      ENDP
END
```

Comment: Can you pass them to printf?  If not you'll have to do number -> string conversion yourself.  [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)

Answer (score 1):

As comment, you can use `printf` with `"%x"` format or `"%lx"` for `long` type.

Or you can use the api [`itoa`/`ltoa`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/itoa-itow?view=vs-2019)